# Removing Attribute hidden from All DOM Elements Except That Whose Index is given Using Javascript Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My Function does not work when i call it.
When I Query All Elements And loop over them. I cant get any effect on the UI.

I need to add attribute `hidden` from all `.question` and remove `.hidden` from the one whose index is passed to the Js function. classes when i call the function.

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-12 question" hidden="hidden" id="D1">
1
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 mb-12 question" hidden="hidden" id="D2">
2
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 mb-12 question" hidden="hidden" id="D3">
3
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 mb-12 question" hidden="hidden">
4
</div>
```

Calling the lines in the If condition alone without the loop works.
What could i not be doing right here.

```
function hideothersexcept(index){
    var ALLQNS = $('.question');
    for (i = -1; i < ALLQNS.length; i++) {
        if (index == i) {
            $('#' + getid(index)).removeAttr('hidden')
        } else {
            ALLQNS[index].setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
        }
    }
}
function getid(elm) {
     var ALLQNS = $('.question');
     k = ALLQNS[elm].getAttribute("id");
     return k;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? Why do you loop with `i = -1` ?

Comment: no errors. At first  i started with i=0 but no effect.

Comment: You don't have any ID on this example. How do you want to get it here:
        $('#' + getid(index)).removeAttr('hidden')? Maybe change it to ALLQNS.removeAttr('hidden')?

Comment: I have an ID in my code . I posted the code without it. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code its more clean and succinct then manually looping through all divs and more importantly it works :)

```
function hideothersexcept(index){                
    $('.question').each(function(elIndex, el){
            if(elIndex == index){
            $(el).removeAttr('hidden');
        }else{
            $(el).attr('hidden', 'hidden');
        }
    });   
}

hideothersexcept(1);
```

It will hide all other dive except div containing number 2.

NOTE: indexing is zero-based :)

Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Great! happy to help :) Please accept the answer and upvote :)